# how to scrape web page that is not written directly using HTML, but is auto-generated using JavaScript?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape http://washingtonmonthly.com/college_guide?ranking=2016-rankings-national-universities website.

This website is auto-generated using JavaScript to update the DOM tree.I have tried below Selenium code for getting the elements inside table, but it returns an empty list.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrme\\chromedriver")
driver.get('http://washingtonmonthly.com/college_guide?ranking=best-colleges-for-adult-learners-4-year-colleges')
time.sleep(5)
test = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByClassName('tablesaw tablesaw-swipe')")
print(test)
```

Is there a way to run those scripts and get the HTML code ? I am using Python 3.6

Comment: I want that table in CSV format. That table has class 'tablesaw tablesaw-swipe'. But that HTML will get populated once that Javascript runs.

Comment: You need to spend some time reading some basic tutorials, learn about proper locators, and how to wait. Once you do that and try some other approaches, come back and edit the question and add those attempts and the results.

Comment: If you open `Network` tab and hit refresh page you can spot [this link](http://wm-college-guide.herokuapp.com/rankings/2016-rankings-national-universities) where you can get all info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this script and I suppose it will give you everything the table contains including a csv output.

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
outfile = open('table_data.csv','w',newline='')
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
driver.get("http://washingtonmonthly.com/college_guide?ranking=2016-rankings-national-universities")

wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it("iFrameResizer0"))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.tablesaw')))

tab_data = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('table.tablesaw')
list_rows = [[cell.text for cell in row.find_elements_by_css_selector('td')]
             for row in tab_data.find_elements_by_css_selector('tr')]
for data in list_rows:
    writer.writerow(data)
    print(data)

driver.quit()
```

Btw, I'm assuming that you have lxml library installed.

Answer (score -1):

First off, when I enter the link it says that the page doesn't exists.

Then if you want to get an auto generated page you have to use the chrome dev tools and see which request are executing the code.

So if you see a GET request that is returning the generated html, you have to take that request and use it in your code.

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: http://washingtonmonthly.com/college_guide?ranking=2016-rankings-national-universities